# Acceso a propiedades internas cuyo objeto contenedor tiene nombre variable y es a su vez contenido

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente objeto Json

```
{
  _id: 5f18915a6a989440440ab5df,
  orderPaymentId: 'PAYID-L4MJCXA3PR83351NL856951G',
  orderPaymentGateway: 'Paypal',
  orderTotal: 150,
  orderShipping: 0,
  orderItemCount: 1,
  orderProductCount: 1,
  orderCustomer: 5f160d5131fc9d0e200978ba,
  orderCompany: 'Eshop',
  orderFirstname: 'ALBERTO',
  orderAddr2: '',
  orderCountry: 'Mexico',
  orderComment: '',
  orderStatus: 'Enviado',
  orderDate: 2020-07-22T19:19:54.296Z,
  orderProducts: {
    '5f1548869916ca0017e10632': {
      productId: 5f1548869916ca0017e10632,
      title: 'Manual node Js',
      quantity: 1,
      totalItemPrice: 150,
      productImage: '/uploads/5f1548869916ca0017e10632/Captura_de_pantalla_(229).png',
      productComment: null,
      productSubscription: null,
      variantId: null,
      variantTitle: null,
      link: 'manual-node-js'
    }
  },
  orderType: 'Single'
}
```

¿cómo puedo accede a la propiedad ProductId?, teniendo en cuenta que 5f1548869916ca0017e10632 es dinámico, no siempre es el mismo valor, pero las propiedades de adentro son las mismas, porque 5f1548869916ca0017e10632 son Ids de productos.

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: `(node:9628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: orders.orderProducts.values is not a function`

Comment: La información la recupero de aquí: `const orders = await db.orders.findOne({ _id: getId(req.body.id_orden) });`

Comment: Excelente, ¡funcionó! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La solución es acceder a los values del objeto Json de la siguiente forma: `Object.values(orders.orderProducts)[0].productId;`